Mader's theorem (Large degree force a minor)(Proof by induction)
Mader's theorem states that If the average degree of $G$ (which has $n$ vertices) is at least $2^{t-2}$ then $G$ has a $K_t$ minor.
Proof: We proceed by induction on $t+n$. If $t=2$, then the average degree of $G$ is at least $1$ . This means $G$ has an edge; this is a $K_2$ minor.
Suppose now that $\bar{d}(G) \geq 2^{t-1}$, i.e., $e(G) \geq 2^{t-2} n$. Let $v$ be any vertex and let $u \in N(v)$. If $u$ and $v$ have at most $2^{t-2}-1$ common neighbours, contract the edge $e=(u, v)$. Note that the number of
vertices of $G / e$ is one less than the number of vertices of $G$ and that the number of edges in $G / e$ decreased by at most $\left(2^{t-2}-1\right)+1=2^{t-2}$ (note that when we contract $e$ we lose the edge $e$, and one edge for every common neighbour of $u$ and $v$ ). Thus,
$$
\bar{d}(G / e)=\frac{2 e(G / e)}{n-1} \geq \frac{2\left(e(G)-2^{t-2}\right)}{n-1} \geq \frac{2^{t-1} n-2^{t-1}}{n-1}=2^{t-1} .
$$
Therefore, by induction $G / e$ has a $K_{t+1}$ minor and so $G$ also has one. We may assume now that for every $u \in N(v)$ the vertices $u$ and $v$ have at least $2^{t-2}$ common neighbours. In that case it is clear that $G^{\prime}=G[N(v)]$ has $\bar{d}\left(G^{\prime}\right) \geq 2^{t-2}$. Thus, by induction $G^{\prime}$ has a $K_t$ minor which, together with $v$, gives a $K_{t+1}$ minor in $G$.

My question is The proof is using induction on $n+t$ (Quite confused about the procedure of doing so, what is the base of the induction and what is the induction step?) We have shown that when $t=2$, for all $n$, the statement is hold, so the statement holds for all $2+n$, so all $\Bbb{N}$?


The base case would be $t+n = 4$ since $t \geq 2, n \geq 2$ and showing it for any $n$ and $t = 2$ implies the base case.
The induction step is split into 2 cases. Let $G$ be a graph with $\overline{d}(G) \geq 2^{t-1}$, that is $\geq 2^{t'-2}, t'=t+1$ . If we find some adjacent vertices $u,v$ with $\leq 2^{t-2}-1$ common neighbors, then we may contract the edge connecting them to get a graph on $n-1$ vertices with average degree $\geq 2^{t-1}$. Then, since the t parameter in the contracted graph is the same as in G, and the vertices decreased by one, their sum also decreased by one so we may apply induction to find a $K_{t+1}$ minor.
Now assume any pair of adjacent vertices share at least $2^{t-2}$ neighbors. Then look at the subgraph induced by the neighborhood of $v$. Clearly it still satisfies the average degree assumption. Further, since we removed at least one vertex, namely $v$, the sum of $t$ and the number of vertices has decreased by one so we may apply induction again.
Note the necessity of inducting over the sum. In every case we use the fact that a different parameter decreased, and thus their sum decreased.
